# If and DoUntil VBA code wont display output

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

Cant seem to figure out why my code is not showing output. New VBA programmer only know basics so any help would be helpful.

What I want is for Excel to start checking a specific column for a specific text1 and then start copying and pasting those values till it reaches text2. After that I want it to check the next fifth column in the same manner.
If you could suggest modifications to my code.
Without putting in a for loop for the column my code looks like this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim a As Long

    y = 1 'starts with the first column
    x = 1  'first row
    a = 70 'this is the row where i want the data to be posted

    If Cells(x, y).Value = "text1" Then 'check first for specific text
        Do Until Cells(x, y).Value = "text2" 'stop here
            Cells(a, y).Value = Cells(x, y).Value 'copy that data to new row
            Cells(a, y + 1).Value = Cells(x, y + 1).Value 'and the column adjacent to it
            x = x + 1
            a = a + 1
        Loop
    Else
        x = x + 1 'if not on that row then check the next row       
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works fine if there is "text1" in first row. If not, it just adds 1 to `x` and does nothing else. You can add one more loop to check again `If Cells(x, y).Value = "text1"` or add `GoTo` statement. If you want to check how your code is working you can press F8. It will run your code line by line and results will be immediately seen in worksheet.

Comment: THANKYOU SO MUCH! Added go to after my else and it worked! @EganWolf

Answer (score 1):

Really hard to see what is going wrong here as your code should be doing what you want.

The only other thing that could throw your results is when you have different `case` ,as VBA will treat a string with an upper case character as being different, so you may not actually be entering the loop at all. And I am assuming that `text1` is just a sample string for the question.

So comparing the string in lower case will ensure that if you have any upper case characters they will be compared correctly, using the `LCase` function should help with that.

Full code,

```
Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()

 Dim x As Long, y As Long
 Dim a As Long

   y = 1 'starts with the first column

    x = 1  'first row
    a = 70 'this is the row where i want the data to be posted
            If LCase(Cells(x, y).Value) = LCase("text1") Then 'check first for specific text
            Do Until LCase(Cells(x, y).Value) = LCase("text2") 'stop here
                Cells(a, y).Value = Cells(x, y).Value 'copy that data to new row
                Cells(a, y + 1).Value = Cells(x, y + 1).Value 'and the column adjacent to it
                x = x + 1
                a = a + 1
            Loop
            Else: x = x + 1 'if not on that row then check the next row

        End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but Egan was right. After checking the first it would stop. Added a GoTo after my else and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hard to see the big picture but I think I produced the result you want with:

```
Sub FindText()


Dim textFound As Range
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim a As Long
y = 1 'starts with the first column

x = 0  'first row
a = 70 'this is the row where i want the data to be posted

Set textFound = ActiveSheet.Columns(y).Cells.Find("Text1")

Do Until textFound.Offset(x, 0).Value = "Text2"

    Cells(a + x, y).Value = textFound.Offset(x, 0).Value
    Cells(a + x, y + 1).Value = textFound.Offset(x, 1).Value
    x = x + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

This code is far from perfect but should work in most circumstances.